# Unable to connect to SSH using my Univ. VPN

Tags: proxy, ssh, centos, vpn

I can connect to my VPS SSH from my home internet connection.

However, I cant connect to SSH via my Univ internet connection.

What I know is that my University uses VPN, and maybe proxy.

My professor told me that the connection port to SSH is open in the University.

Is there any possible reason to this?

my VPS is centOS 5.4

Thank You,

Answer (score 1):

If you can set up an ssh tunnel through your home computer, you can access it like that.

`ssh -t reachable_host ssh unreachable_host`

Reference
 - http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1339/ssh-connection-through-host-in-the-middle#comment